# Why post's view changes while editing?

Tags: bug, suggested-edits, edits

I wanted to edit a post.  This is a screenshot of before the edit:

> [image: The post's view before edit]

Then I clicked "edit" button. Astonishing, this post lost it's beauty. Below is screenshot of after clicking `edit` button:

> [image: Post's view after edit button clicked.]

Why did this happen?  Should I format all this from scratch?

**PS**: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9491312/ignoring-the-year-in-sql-query-with-date-range/) to post used in screenshot.

Comment: No repro. What browser are you using?

Comment: Not reproducable in Chrome latest beta.

Comment: I took a screenshot in Firefox 15.0. After your comment, I also checked in Chrome 26.0.1410.64 m. Result is same.

Comment: The link you added leads to the accepted answer, not the question.

Comment: @bob: can't repro with that exact version of Chrome. Did you try clearing your cache? (And make sure you didn't disable JavaScript.)

Comment: @Ren Thanks, I updated the link with more correct one.

Comment: Check the loaded JavaScript files. Are any failing to load? Could be that one is being blocked by your browser/provider/employer causing this issue.

Comment: @Oded, @Mat My JavaScript is enabled. All js files are loaded. I've seen this issue multiples times with many posts while editing. I've `adblock` on my browser and while checking console I saw `WebSocket connection to 'ws://sockets.ny.stackexchange.com/' failed: Unexpected response code: 502`. I don't think it's cause to error.

Comment: Assumptions are the mother of all.... does it work when you disable your freeloading-kill-all-website-revenue-so-they-can't-survive plugin?

Comment: Disabling `adblock` didn't help. I was using a proxy. I turned it off. Cheers, editing posts is showing like a charm in Chrome. However, disabling adblock, proxy not helped in Firefox. So now, Chrome shows well, but Firefox has same issue.

Comment: Are you sure FF is not still using the same proxy, or that FF is not using a stale version of the JavaScript?

Comment: @Oded You're mentor. I cannot believe I missed that. I needed to configure separately each browser. I disabled proxy in FF, now edit posting is working as expected. I don't know why that happened. Thank you. Can you answer with your thoughts? I'll accept that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The symptoms you have seen and the fact that others were not able to reproduce point at an issue on your end - something is blocking some of the JavaScript.

From your comments, it appears that you are using a proxy that is blocking web sockets (which we use a lot here on Stack Exchange, for various things), causing the issue you have seen.

Unblocking web sockets (either by disabling this proxy or another way) should solve the issue.